# update set не работает в php mysql c длинным текстом

Tags: php, mysql

```
$block1 = $row['block1'];
$block2 = $row['block2'];
<textarea class="form-control" name="b1"><?=$block1?></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" name="b2"><?=$block2?></textarea>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
$b1 = $_POST['b1'];
$b2 = $_POST['b2'];
$link->query("UPDATE meta SET block1='$b1', block2='$b2'");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /admin/meta'>";
}
?>
```

Подскажите почему не могу вставить длинную строку в базу с этой формы? mysqli_real_escape_string не помогает, в базе и так стоит text, ставил и long, бесполезно...

Comment: Используйте привязку переменных https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php и после запроса обрабатывайте результаты выполнения и выводите ошибки, если они были. А то может вам там БД что нибудь интересное пишет, например что данные не влезают в колонку

Comment: Что значит _не могу вставить_? Какая ошибка?

Comment: @Mike В базе я могу сделать апдейт, но вот с php - просто не уходит :/

Comment: Скорее всего текст с какими нибудь апострофами и надо эскейпить